# Include static common header / footer with CherryPy

Tags: python, python-2.7, include, cherrypy

I am using cherryPy to create a simple python web app. I plan on having a few pages with most likely identical header / footer. How can I include or merge header / footer with for example index.html static page?

Right now I am able to have the whole static page returned or dynamic content:

```
return open('index.html')
#or
return("dynamic content")
```

In PHP you would simply include it but in python / cherrypy there does not seem to be a simple way of achieving this. Perhaps my idea of how cherrypy works is wrong. I could go with html generated by cherrypy but I don't like the fact that I would be dealing with escaping issues just for static html, not to mention the lack of proper syntax highlighting etc...

What is a good way to have a common header and footer with cherrypy?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

from cherrypy docs

> CherryPy does not provide a built-in support for database access,
>   **HTML templating** or any other middleware nifty features.

so you would need to either create your own content serve function that includes your header and footer, or use javascript to load the header/footer, or download a 3rd party library that provides html templating (like JINJA), or switch to something like flask that already has a templating engine

Comment: Was hoping this wasn't considered templating as such, will look into flash and templates next, thanks!